# When I deploy my laravel project on server I get this error try{r.send(i.hasContent&&i.data||null) but on my localhost it works perfectly

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, server, send

This is my ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 function fetch_customer_data(query = ''){
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data){
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
    alert(data.table_data); 
    alert(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }


 $(document).on('click', '#find', function(){

   var query = $(search).val();
   alert(query); 
   fetch_customer_data(query);

   return false;
 });


});
</script>
```

I think the problem is all about the ajax code, instead I don't know why it doesn't work on server but localhost

Comment: Your code seems to be working please debug the code by adding `console.log` and check the url is correct. Use firebug to see the request are sending correcly on both live and localhost. Try all possibilities before posting your question here. We cannot directly check as no error found in your code

Comment: sorry but it has been all week i'm working on this issu but i didn't find any think i dont know where's the error me niether tha's why i've post it here the only error i have is on browser inspector ** jquery.js:2 GET http://172.30.23.28/live_search/action?query=1497208 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.js:2
ajax @ jquery.js:2
fetch_customer_data @ ?search=1497208&find=:69
(anonymous) @ ?search=1497208&find=:99
dispatch @ jquery.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.js:2 **

Comment: URL not found issue is not something related to this code , Can you first find it out why http://172.30.23.28/live_search/action?query=1497208  not working

Comment: that's my problem, when i search the value on the link at this state i'm calling my ajax function and here is the issu, i've added an alert message on the ajax function it said undefinde so why ?? i'm trying to figure it out